# Which inflation models does BICEP3 rule out?

Tags: cosmological-inflation, cosmic-microwave-background

[Polarization data from BICEP3](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.127.151301) combined with BICEP2 and *Keck* in a recent analysis [is reported to](https://www6.slac.stanford.edu/news/2021-10-25-bicep3-tightens-bounds-cosmic-inflation.aspx) rule out several simpler categories of inflation models.  Which are these?  e.g. single-inflaton models?

Comment: The paper can be read at the arxiv https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.00483 , but it needs somebody with working  knowledge of the  models to come up with the conclusions in your link. Maybe there is someone here. Also here a commentary https://www.symmetrymagazine.org/article/bicep3-tightens-the-bounds-on-cosmic-inflation